# How can I trend KPI's with Medium & Source by date in Google BigQuery?

Tags: sql, google-bigquery, analytics, channel

I am wanting to code custom marketing channels by certain criteria, by day such as the below:

```
SELECT
date, 
trafficSource.medium,
case
when trafficSource.medium like '%cpc%' then 'Paid Search'
end as channel
FROM `xyz.ga_sessions_2017*`
limit 1000
```

This gives me the result of

```
date       |   medium   |   channel
--------------------------------------
20171212   |     cpc    |  Paid Search
```

I can also trend my KPI's like so

```
SELECT
date,
SUM(totals.visits) visits,
SUM(totals.pageviews) pageviews,
SUM(totals.transactions) transactions,
SUM(totals.transactionRevenue)/1000000 revenue
FROM `xyz.ga_sessions_2017*`
GROUP BY
date
ORDER BY
date ASC
```

which gives me this result

```
date       |   visits   |    pageviews  |   transactions  | revenue
--------------------------------------------------------------------
20171212   |    1234    |      5678     |     1111        | 99999
```

However my objective is to bring these two together which should appear something like:

```
date     | medium  |   channel     | visits |    pageviews  |   transactions  | revenue
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
20171211 |  cpc    | Paid Search   |  18    |      50       |     17          |    2578  
20171212 |  cpc    | Paid Search   |  27    |      90       |     35          |    2981
```

Any tips or suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Below is for BigQuery Standard SQL

```sql
#standardSQL
SELECT
  DATE, 
  trafficSource.medium,
  CASE 
    WHEN trafficSource.medium LIKE '%cpc%' THEN 'Paid Search'
    ELSE trafficSource.medium
  END AS channel,
  SUM(totals.visits) visits,
  SUM(totals.pageviews) pageviews,
  SUM(totals.transactions) transactions,
  SUM(totals.transactionRevenue)/1000000 revenue  
FROM `xyz.ga_sessions_2017*`
GROUP BY DATE, medium, channel
ORDER BY DATE ASC
LIMIT 1000
```